# Uibutton in Wepopover Control

Tags: iphone, ios

How to include uibutton in WEpopover controller ,I want a set of 3 buttons in WEpopover,On click navigates to other view.Where should i change in WEpopover controller?

Comment: `-viewDidLoad` is the most common place to set up programmatic UI hierarchies.

Comment: @CodaFi But where it will be include in the popover controller.when i click

Comment: So, let me clarify something first:  You have a popover with three buttons set up already, but now you want to push a new view into the popover when the buttons are clicked?

Comment: My doubt is how can i include three buttons in WEpopover controller @CodaFi

Comment: Ah!  I see.  Perhaps you should read up on [view controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html) and [view hierarchies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820094/programmatically-creating-views-in-ios-how-does-it-work) then.  It's a trivial task to add subviews to a view in iOS.

Answer (score 1):

Underneath the hood, WEPopover works by adding a subview, a 'container', to the `mainWindow`, which is a subclass of `UIView` that is at the very root of your hierarchy of views[1]. To that container, it adds the `view` property of a given view controller. To know how to size that view, it asks the view controller for its `contentSizeForViewInPopover`.

Because of this, the way you setup your 3 buttons is the same way you would setup 3 buttons for any other view controller. The only difference is that in your `UIViewController` subclass that handles the 3 buttons, you need to set your `contentSizeForViewInPopover`.

You can set this property in `init` or `viewDidLoad`. (Remember to add it to the correct `init` method -- if e.g. you're making this view controller in a storyboard, `init` will not be called but instead `initWithCoder:`).

To actually add the buttons, you would probably want some code like this in `viewDidLoad`:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

[1] If you asked a view for its superview, and then asked THAT view for its superview, and so on, you would eventually reach the `mainWindow`.

Comment: -init would be best, but they both work.

Comment: Two things here that are nagging me:  1) The container is not a UIView, it's a UIWindow.  2) The OP seems a bit of a novice, perhaps you could explain what the way to set up the buttons would be (a little pseudo-code never hurt nobody).  +1 anyhow.

Comment: CodaFi, in the implementation of WEPopover I'm currently using, the WEPopoverContainerView is a subclass of UIView. But I was saying that the window is literally `aKindOfClass` of `UIView` because I think that makes the concept of a window relatable. I'll clarify that it's a subclass in the post and add some sample code.